# How to get GWT dates to be formatted correctly?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

How do you get today's date in MM/dd/yyyy format?  I've followed the docs and examples.  This is supposed to do it:

```
Date today = new Date();
DateTimeFormat fm = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String date = fm.format(today);
return new Object[][] {
        new Object[] { "This is a note", date},
        new Object[] { "This is a very very very long note", date}
};
```

But instead it puts the following in the date cell of the grid:

> Sun Mar 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

So then I tried to do it javascript like this:

```
public native String getTodaysDate() /*-{
    return new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    }-*/;

private Object[][] getNoteData() {
    String date = getTodaysDate();
```

Which produces the same result.

Such a simple task sucks up so much time!  Suggestions?

**EDIT**: I'm adding more code for people to better diagnose the problem.

```
private Panel createNotesTable() {
    Panel panel = new Panel();

    RecordDef recordDef = new RecordDef(
            new FieldDef[] { 
                    new StringFieldDef("note"), 
                    new DateFieldDef("date"), 
            }
    );

    GridPanel grid = new GridPanel();
    Object[][] data = getNoteData();
    MemoryProxy proxy = new MemoryProxy(data);

    ArrayReader reader = new ArrayReader(recordDef);
    Store store = new Store(proxy, reader);
    store.load();
    grid.setStore(store);

    ColumnConfig[] columns = new ColumnConfig[] {
            new ColumnConfig("Note", "note", 130, true, null, "note"),
            new ColumnConfig("Date", "date", 65, true)
    };
    ColumnModel columnModel = new ColumnModel(columns);
    grid.setColumnModel(columnModel);

    grid.setStripeRows(true);

    panel.add(grid);
    return panel;
}

private Object[][] getNoteData() {
    Date today = new Date();
    DateTimeFormat fm = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String date = fm.format(today);
    GWT.log("date=" +date);  //date is formatted correctly
    //but when it is put into the cell, it gets reformatted back to a long version
     return new Object[][] {
            new Object[] { "This is a note", date},
            new Object[] { "This is a very very very long note", date}
    };
}
```

Comment: Javascript time display is pretty annoying, these docs have more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat but I would suggest using a library like dayjs or moment if formatting date in javascript

Comment: It looks like you are using DateTimeFormat correctly. If you are using dev mode, could it there be a caching problem perhaps?  Perhaps log the string to the console with GWT.log() or DomGlobal.console.debug(), just to simplify things

Comment: Thanks for the GWT.log() tip (I'm new to GWT).  It is outputting the date in the correct format so it must be the Grid that is changing it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was because I was using a

```
new DateFieldDef("date")
```

instead of

```
new StringFieldDef("date"),
```

Thanks to commenters for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to just [use locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#using_locales):

```js
String date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(today)
```